# Rebase default router in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I try to rebase basic router on my own but I have provider error and I couldn't understand what's going on.

root ngmodule:

```
              imports     : [
                  ...
                  RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
              ],
              providers   : [
                  {
                      provide : Router,
                      useClass: GlobalRouter
                  },
              ]
```

Part of GlobalRouter:

```
export class GlobalRouter extends Router {

    constructor(rootComponentType: Type, resolver: ComponentResolver, urlSerializer: UrlSerializer, outletMap: RouterOutletMap, location: Location, injector: Injector, loader: NgModuleFactoryLoader, config: Routes) {
        super(rootComponentType, resolver, urlSerializer, outletMap, location, injector, loader, config);
    }

    navigate(commands: any[], extras?: NavigationExtras): Promise<boolean> {
        ...some logic
        super(commands, extras);
    }
}
```

The error:

```
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider for Function!
```

Comment: `ROUTER_PROVIDERS` is deprecated, remove it. Instead use either `RouterModule.forRoot(...)` or `RouterModule.forChild(...)` and it will setup correct providers for you (see [docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html)). I don't promise it will work after this, but those are definitely errors in your approach.

Comment: I use RouterModule.fromRoot(). Removing ROUTER_PROVIDER has no effect. And they are not mark as deprecarted.